# $\partial{y} = \text{Trace}(A)y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, fundamental-solution

[image]Let $Y$ be the fundamental solution matrix for an $nxn$-system $\partial{y} = Ay$. Also, with $\det(Y) \neq 0 $. Prove that $\det(Y)$ satisfies $\partial{y} = \text{Trace}(A)y$. Also show that the columns of $Y^{-1}$ satisfy the system of equations $\partial{y} = -A^ty$, where $A^t$ denotes the transpose of $A$.

I have minimal knowledge of differential equations, I am reading F. Beuker's notes in differential equations because I need them for my research in Number theory. Could someone please guide me how to solve the above problem? It is an exercise in Beuker's notes.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: You say, "prove that det(Y) satisfies..." but the following expression does not involve a det(Y) term?

Comment: @JacobA I have used the same wording as the text I am reading. My understanding is that we replace $y$ by $det(Y)$ in the equation.

Comment: I don't think that can be the case, or am having a hard time seeing it. Can you also double check your usage of capital vs. lowercase $y$?

Comment: @JacobA I have attached picture of the text.

Comment: This is Liouville's formula: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_formula.

Answer (score 1):

The first question asks you to prove Liouville's formula in the case of a constant matrix $A$. For the general case, there are plenty of proofs over the internet, e.g. on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_formula).

For the constant case, a direct approach could be the following:

1. Show that $Y(t)=e^{(t-t_0)A}$ (check that $y(t)=e^{(t-t_0)A}y_0$ is the unique solution of the initial value problem when $y(t_0)=y_0$)
2. Show that for a square matrix $M$, $\det{(e^{M})}=e^{Tr(M)}$
3. Continue the calculation of $\frac{d}{dt}det (e^{(t-t_0)A}) = ...$ then conclude the proof.

The second question asks you about the "dual" of the system, or its "costate equation". To me, but I can be mistaken, there is a typo in Beukers' notes, and the exercise should be to prove that the *rows* of $Y^{-1}$ satisfy the given system. Knowing $Y(t)=e^{(t-t_0)A}$, you just have to leverage the fact that for a square matrix $M$, $(e^M)^{T}=e^{(M^{T})}$ and $(e^M)^{-1}=e^{-M}$.